# Uninstall Oracle

Tags: oracle-10g

How to uninstall oracle 10g XE from pc. I have tried uninstalling from Control Panel>Programs but it didn't work. I have also deleted registry folders in Registory Editor but it didn't work. Actually i want to reinstall oracle 10g xe again, earlier it was showing an error your system has OracleServerXE file so you first need to delete it. Now it is showing "Installer has detected Oracle Database 10g Express(universal)Edition on this system. Oracle Database 10g Express(universal)Edition and Oracle Database 10g Express(western union)Edition cannot coexist."

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to uninstall it using the Revo Uninstaller tool but still if there is any other manual method to do it I would like to know.